# MySQL indexing columns vs joining tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to extract values from database that has the structure similar to this:

table test:

```
int id (primary, auto increment)
varchar(50) stuff,
varchar(50) important_stuff;
```

where I need to do a query like

```
select * from test where important_stuff like 'prefix%';
```

The size of the entire table is approximately 10 million rows, however there are only about 500-1000 distinct values for important_stuff. My current solution is indexing `important_stuff` however the performance is not satisfactory. Will it be better to create a separate table that will match distinct `important_stuff` to a certain id, which will be stored in the 'test' table and then do

`(select id from stuff_lookup where important_stuff like 'prefix%') a join select * from test b where b.stuff_id=a.id`

or this:

`select * from test where stuff_id exists in(select id from stuff_lookup where important_stuff like 'prefix%')`

What is the best way to optimize things like that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? mysql <> sqlserver

Comment: This seems like a situation where doing some hands on testing would benefit you. Try creating your second table and then try your two test use cases and see which performs better. I can't speak for anyone else, but I don't have a 10 million record test database lying around with to test ;)

Comment: "*the performance is not satisfactory*"—however, based on your problem description, such an index is close to optimal (only a covering index would be better as the resultset could be returned directly from the index file without looking aside into the table itself).  Chances are, however, that your description has oversimplified your problem... please could we see the actual query that you're using, together with it's execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM is available?  The former should be about 70% of the latter.  You'll see in a minute why I bring up this setting.

Based on your 3 suggested SELECTs, the original one will work as good as the two complex ones.  In some *other* case, the complex formulation might work better.

`INDEX(important_stuff)` is the 'best' index for

```
select * from test where important_stuff like 'prefix%';
```

Now, let's study how that query works with that index:

1. Reach into the BTree index, starting at 'prefix'.  (Effort: Virtually instantaneous)
2. Scan forward for, say, 1000 entries.  That will be about 10 InnoDB blocks (16KB each).  Each entry will have the PRIMARY KEY (`id`).  (Effort:  <= 10 disk hits)
3. For each entry, look up the row (so you can get "*").  That's 1000 PK lookups in the BTree that contains both the PK and the data.  At best, they might all be in 10 blocks.  At worst, they could be in 1000 separate blocks.  (Effort:  10-1000 blocks)

Total Effort:  ~1010 blocks (worst case).

A standard spinning disk can handle ~100 reads/second.  So. we are looking at 10 seconds.

Now, run the query again.  Guess what; all those blocks are now in RAM (cached in the "buffer_pool", which is *hopefully* big enough for all of them).  And it runs in less than 1 second.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` was *not* necessary!  It was *not* a statistics refresh, but rather *caching* that sped up the query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not MySQL user but I made some tests on my local database. I've added 10 millions rows as you wrote and distinct datas from third column are loaded quite fast. These are my results.

```
mysql> describe bigtable;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stuff           | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| important_stuff | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from bigtable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 10000089 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.87 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct important_stuff) from bigtable;
+---------------------------------+
| count(distinct important_stuff) |
+---------------------------------+
|                            1000 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select distinct important_stuff from bigtable;
....
| is_987          |
| is_988          |
| is_989          |
| is_99           |
| is_990          |
| is_991          |
| is_992          |
| is_993          |
| is_994          |
| is_995          |
| is_996          |
| is_997          |
| is_998          |
| is_999          |
+-----------------+
1000 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

Important information is that I refreshed statistics on this table (before this operation I needed ~10 seconds to load these data).

```
mysql> optimize table bigtable;
```

Comment: `ANALYZE TABLE` will refresh the statistics without rebuilding the table.